# Is the following a Wiener process?

Tags: brownian-motion

This is a worked example on Wiener processes.

> **Question**: Pick a normally distributed random variable $Z \sim N(0,1)$, then define $W(t) = Z\sqrt{t}$. Is $W(t)$ a Wiener process?
>
> **Answer:**
>
> 1. It is continuous.
> 2. $W(0) = 0$.
>
> Therefore two required properties are satisfied.
>
> However, $W(t+s) - W(s) = Z(\sqrt{t+s}-\sqrt{s})$; which has variance $(\sqrt{t+s}-\sqrt{s})^2$ so it is not a Wiener process as the incremental change in such a process should be $Z \sim N(0,t)$ also.

I don't understand how the example arrived at $(\sqrt{t+s}-\sqrt{s})$ as the number evaluated within the normal distribution (why the square root?) nor how the variance of the increment is $(\sqrt{t+s}-\sqrt{s})^2$. I think I am missing some knowledge about manipulating $t + s$ and $t$. Can someone kindly break down the manipulation into simple steps, I would be so grateful! Or otherwise explain how to arrive at the conclusion based on the third property? Yeah, I know I am not the best at maths!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since $W(t+s)=aZ$ and $W(s)=bZ$ for some $a$ and $b$, $W(t+s)-W(s)=(a-b)Z$. Since the variance of $Z$ is $1$, the variance of $(a-b)Z$ is $(a-b)^2$.

Now, set $a=\sqrt{t+s}$ and $b=\sqrt{s}$.

Comment: Oh we are just using the formula $W(t) = Z\sqrt{t}$. $Z$ is a random variable so we are multiplying by the bracketed expression. Would it be correct to state $W(t+s) - W(s) = Z(\sqrt{t+s}) -Z(\sqrt{s}) = Z(\sqrt{t+s}-\sqrt{s})$

Comment: With regard to the variance would it also be correct to state $var((a+b)Z) = (a+b)^2var(z)$? My error was not to realise in the notation that $Z$ is just like any other variable!

Comment: Yes, that would be correct (twice), and in fact **this** is what is in my answer, ain't it?

Comment: Yes it is. Thanks so much for your help. I just wanted as much confirmation as possible due to my sketchy maths skills.

Comment: To turn the function $W(t)$ into a Wiener process could we state $W(t) = Z\sqrt{h} $ where $t_j = jh$

Comment: ??? See [the definition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wiener_process#Characterizations_of_the_Wiener_process).

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a very old question but I recently came upon this very same example and I don't agree with the discussion above, although I agree with the conclusion that W(t) is not a Weiner process.

Assuming two random variables X,Y are independent we have these facts:
Var (X + Y) = Var(X) + Var(Y), and also:
Var (X - Y) = Var (X) + Var(Y)
Also if a is a constant, then Var(aX) = a^2*Var(X)

We also know that a normal random variable Z multiplied by a constant "a" is another normal random variable with variance a^2*Var(Z).

According to these facts, we can determine:
Each of W(t + s) and W(s) are normal random variables with variances of (sqrt(t + s))^2 = t + s and (sqrt(s))^2 = s, respectively.

In other words, Var( W(t + s) ) = t + s, and
Var ( W(t) ) = t

Next we know that Var ( W(t + s) - W(s) ) = Var (W(t + s)) + Var (W(s)) = t + s + s = 2s + t

So W(t) is not a Weiner process because its variance is "2s + t", not because its variance is (sqrt(t + s) - sqrt(s))^2.

Comment: Please use LaTeX in your post.